# RQT Topic Monitor displays empty array as non empty

Tags: ros-melodic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I encountered a strange behavior in RQT where is displays an empty array as non empty.

Here's the output of `rostopic echo` and a  screenshot of rqt taken **at the same time** :

[image: image description]

You can clearly see that rqt shows that 1 message (id=0) is in the array even though `rostopic echo` says the length=0 (rostopic echo is right)

RQT dispolays the last state of the array before it was empty.

Am I missing something or is it a bug of rqt or something else ?

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381381/rqt-topic-monitor-displays-empty-array-as-non-empty/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2021-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems to be a bug. Issue here : https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_topic/issues/33

---

Originally posted by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) with karma: 196 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0